# Laravel Eloquent: Where Clause on combined columns (or custom attribute)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to find a solution for this use case.

I have a users table with the fields `first_name` and `last_name` as well as a custom attribute called `full_name`.

```
 public function getFullNameAttribute()
 {
    return ucfirst($this->name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->last_name);
 }
```

Now I am looking for a way to filter through `first_name` and `last_name` or `full_name` at the same time.
Example:

Searching for `Sebastian Mendez` should find users like the following examples:

| first_name | last_name | found |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Juan Sebastian | Mendez Tellez | true |
| Sebastian Mendez | Tellez | true |
| Juan | Sebastian Mendez | true |
| Sebastian | Tellez | false |
| Juan | Mendez | false |

I can't get my head around it, I tried to split the search text into separate strings like this:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search){
 $str = "Sebastian Mendez";
 $str = explode(" ",$search);
 $query->whereIn('first_name', $str)->andWhereIn('last_name', $str);
}
```

But then it returns as well the other results or none.
I guess the problem is the following:

> **I don't know which part of the string is part of the first or last name...**

Comment: Is it correct to say that for your search, both parts of the name MUST appear, but they can be spread across both first and last name?

Comment: Exactly! The parts could be all in the last_name or first_name or spreaded between last_name, first_name

Comment: With Postgres you could do some much friendlier array_intersect stuff but a dirty solution could look like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25668d1/10 Exercise left to reader to Eloquent-ify it (nb: for that to work the name parts must be in-order, but can appear anywhere which is I think what you're after. For names to appear anywhere add a wildcard in the middle of the search term name)

Comment: Awesome, I think that's a good start. Thanks a lot!